# LDAP validation using email address?

Tags: php, ldap, ldapconnection

I am using LDAP validation , now LDAP id am using and its working fine.

I want to use email instead of ldap id. How can i add that.

What will be LDAP config for this ?

now this is working
$username='ou=users,o=example.com';

this is not working
  $username='mail='.$user.',ou=users,o=example.com';

how to use email for ldap validation

I found some documents that i listed as answer below. But now it is returning a message

[_messages:protected] => Array
        (
            **[0] => Authority not found: uid=**

What is that mean?